# Use .htaccess to load files from different folders

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, url-masking

I have many files in directory `/full/`

that's why I would like to spread files to `/full1/`, `/full2/`, `/full3/` folders on server but to save original URL like

```
http://my-domain.com/full/article-with-text
```

to determine which files are where to put I'd like to define it on the URL mask like

`^/full/a$` from folder `/full1/`

`^/full/b$` from folder `/full2/`

tell me please how to build correct .htaccess ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^full/a(.+)?/?$ http://my-domain.com/full1/a$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^full/b(.+)?/?$ http://my-domain.com/full2/b$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^full/c(.+)?/?$ http://my-domain.com/full3/c$1 [NC,L]
...
RewriteRule ^full/z(.+)?/?$ http://my-domain.com/full26/z$1 [NC,L]
```

e.g,

`http://my-domain.com/full/a-one.txt`
will mask the url
`http://my-domain.com/full1/a-one.txt`

Comment: why it's need `R=302` flag? Search engines will think that i'd like to move page, but I'd like only load file from another folder and keep original URL

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question, answer has been updated, just remove the [R] flag then you'll have the silent redirect.